# How to get a meaningful value for PROPERTYKEY from OnPropertyValueChanged()

Tags: windows, audio, wasapi

I am implementing the callback methods from `MMNotificationClient` to get notified of audio device changes.

When I change the "spatial sound" settings for the Windows audio driver, then `MMNotificationClient::OnPropertyValueChanged()` gets called multiple times.

However, I am unsure how to interpret the `PROPERTYKEY` value that is supplied to this method in any meaningful way.

I can simply print the raw key data, e.g.

```
printf("  -->Changed device property "
              "{%8.8x-%4.4x-%4.4x-%2.2x%2.2x-%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x}#%d\n",
              key.fmtid.Data1, key.fmtid.Data2, key.fmtid.Data3,
              key.fmtid.Data4[0], key.fmtid.Data4[1],
              key.fmtid.Data4[2], key.fmtid.Data4[3],
              key.fmtid.Data4[4], key.fmtid.Data4[5],
              key.fmtid.Data4[6], key.fmtid.Data4[7],
              key.pid);
```

This gives me output such as:

```
 -->Changed device property {1e94c58f-3e40-4ddb-b10c-a86d8b870a31}#2
```

But how do I get from this e.g. the *name* of a property that has changed?

The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/device-properties) are very unclear on this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to convert propertykeys to names at runtime. If your code doesn't recognize a property, it should just ignore it.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks but how do I find out what the keys actually correspond to? Is there a pre-defined list somewhere? For example if the user changes a spatial sound setting or "volume" how does my code recognise that property?

Comment: Since anyone can define a property key, there is no central location that gathers all property keys. Some are in `mfplay.h`, some in `mfidl.h`, some in `mmdeviceapi.h`... In general, the documentation a feature should explain what property keys it uses. The specific one you show above does not appear to be documented.

Comment: In theory PSGetNameFromPropertyKey or PSGetPropertyDescription  should work (I would expect this from a good OS if there is NO documentation about what properties to expect at all), unfortunately the functions don't help :(

Comment: there is a good list in the bottom of the file of what it might be (the list is not full) https://github.com/mvaneerde/blog/blob/develop/audioendpoints/audioendpoints/stringify.cpp and it seems an initial author's blogpost https://matthewvaneerde.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/how-to-enumerate-audio-endpoint-immdevice-properties-on-your-system/